# Register user and checking if the user is in database

Tags: php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbusers WHERE email ='$_POST[email]'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
{
    NewUser();
}
else
{
    echo "What's going on with this code?";
}
```

I'm trying to figure out  why this isn't working. Supposed to check if the user trying to register with email is in the database. Thanks1

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `mysql_num_rows` function:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbusers WHERE email ='{$_POST['email']}'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
    echo "What's going on with this code?";
}
else
{
    NewUser();
}
```

**Note:** switch mysql_* functions to mysqli_* functions or use PDO libary. the  are deprecated.

Comment: Check the [string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). `'$_POST[email]'` inside double quotes won't work because of non-space symbol after the closing square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dbusers` WHERE `email` ='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.</sup>

Comment: Can you read a tiny disclaimer below my answer ? If you had read that before, you woudn't have commented. ^_^

Comment: Yes, I read that, but switching to MySQLi or PDO doesn't magically solve SQL injection vulnerabilities. I've seen lots of code with MySQLi that still is vulnerable. One should use *prepared statements* to fix those issues.

Comment: `Prepared Statements` That is corrrect !

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should be using some method to prevent SQL Injection against your database. You can string together a bunch of logic to do this for the deprecated MySQL driver, or you can use the prepared statements inside of MySQLI or PDO. Note, though, that if these extensions aren't configured to use "true prepared statements," that you might still need some light escaping against certain types of values.

Also, if you want it to be nominally faster for small data sets, and considerably faster for large data sets, instead of storing the user's email as you received it, reverse it first. For example, person@world.com would become moc.dlrow@nosrep. Storing emails like this will also make it possible to construct simpler queries when looking for all users who registered with an email from a specific domain.

Comment: They aren't stored faster, but having reversed emails in an indexed column can be faster to query against with certain types of queries.